# Why "There are .debs in this upload, and enforcing they don't exist." when I try to upload package to a PPA?

Tags: ppa, dput

I'm trying to upload some package that I build using `debuild` to a PPA, but it fails with the following:

```
dput ppa:braiampe/ffc ffc_1.3.20140513-1_i386.changes 
Uploading ffc using ftp to ppa (host: ppa.launchpad.net; directory: ~braiampe/ffc/ubuntu)
running supported-distribution: check whether the target distribution is currently supported (using distro-info)
{u'known': [u'release', u'proposed', u'updates', u'backports', u'security'], u'allowed': [u'release']}
running checksum: verify checksums before uploading
running suite-mismatch: check the target distribution for common errors
running check-debs: makes sure the upload contains a binary package
There are .debs in this upload, and enforcing they don't exist.
```

How can I upload the sources to the PPA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you used debuild to build Debian binaries instead of the Debian sources. You should have used `debuild -S` instead. Now, dput-ng error message is too vague, but essentially is saying that there are binary debs and you didn't force for them to be uploaded. [Here is the source of the message](https://github.com/Debian/dput-ng/blob/master/dput/hooks/deb.py#L97):

```py
if not enforce_debs and has_debs:
    raise BinaryUploadError(
        "There are .debs in this upload, and enforcing they don't exist."
    )
```